# throttle / debounce useMemo value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

Are there any ways to debounce/throttle computing values in React with `useMemo`?

I often see solutions to create debounced/throttled **functions** in React, like in this example:

```
const debouncedEventHandler = useMemo(
  () => debounce(eventHandler, 300),
  []
);

const throttledEventHandler = useMemo(
  () => throttle(eventHandler, 300),
  []
);

<button onClick={debouncedEventHandler}>Click Me</button>
```

But what I'm looking for is a way to debounced/throttled **values**, instead of functions, like:

```
const App = ({ veryBigArray }) => {
  // Throttle this value
  const heavyComputedValue = useMemo(
    () => veryBigArray.reduce( ... ),
    [veryBigArray]
  );

  return <div>{heavyComputedValue}</div>
}
```

The `App` will be re-rendering a lot because of the changes in this `veryBigArray`, where the `heavyComputedValue` does not need to be up-to-date on every re-render.

So I'm finding a way to make my `useMemo` only compute the actual value on an interval (throttle), **without** introducing a new state.

Comment: You could try creating a custom hook for the requirement, for example - https://react-use-custom-hooks.vercel.app/docs/useDebounce